# Python Syntax error: blank space

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am new to python, this code is meant to print out the top 100 frequent words in file MusicTaste.csv and print it in a table. I've solved past syntax error, but have never seen this error before.

### Please see code below

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from prettytable import PrettyTable

words = re.findall('\w+',open('MusicTaste2.csv').read().lower())   
for label, data in ('Word', words) THE_ERROR_APPEARS_HERE_BLANK_SPACE

pt = PrettyTable(field_names=[label, 'Count'])
c = Counter(words)
[ pt.add_row(kv) for kv in c.most_common()[:100]

print pt
```

Comment: You need a colon at the end of the line. `for a in b:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from prettytable import PrettyTable

words = re.findall('\w+',open('MusicTaste2.csv').read().lower())   
for label, data in ('Word', words):
    pt = PrettyTable(field_names=[label, 'Count'])
    c = Counter(words)
    [pt.add_row(kv) for kv in c.most_common()[:100]]
    print (pt)
```

First problem is `indent` your code properly

Second problem is missing of `:` in the follwing line

```
for label, data in ('Word', words):
```

Third problem i am seeing is missing of `]` in the following line

```
[pt.add_row(kv) for kv in c.most_common()[:100]]
```

Comment: Note that using a list comprehension and throwing away the value is probably not the thing OP should be doing.